# covariate in ANCOVA

Tags: ancova, mancova

I have two groups I want to compare- drug and placebo- on a few dependent variables from neuropsychological tests. I ran a MANCOVA using only one covariate (related to the DV) and I found two out of three DVs to be significantly different between groups. When I re-ran the MANCOVA adding how alert they were (scale measure prior to testing) all three DVs were significantly different between the groups. The second added covariate though came back as insignificant.

Which of the two results should I keep?
I saw in previous posts the covariate non significance is not a reason to drop it from the analysis- but what happens when it actually changes the results?

Thanks!